# Blur edges of plane in Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I have a simple plane in blender 3D, shadeless, and I'm trying to figure out how to blur the edges of this object.

Apparently there was a blur tab in older versions, I'm using 2.75.

I think this would be helpful for anyone starting out in blender.

Seen some solutions involving nodes but I am sure there is something more simple.
Tried using edit mode, checked the tools and properties and couldn't find anything.
Also checked Material and Texture tabs and nothing does this.

Thanku

Answer (score 0):

Now there's no proper way to blur edges on their own but you could use a radial gradient and map the value of the gradient to the transparency of the plane.